# Unable to use GroupBy on Subselect in EF Core 5/6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, group-by

I am currently trying to implement a Report for a customer using Entity Framework Core 5 (also tested 6) and came across a problem, that I couldn't resolve.

I am trying to query a List of all customers / bank accounts with their total sales per month.
Therefore I am trying to group all of the customers bookings, that fit the criteria, by their Month and sum up their amounts.

Shouldn't be that hard of a task.

This is my Query:

```
context.Kontens
            .Select(k => new
            {
                Creditor = context.DebitorKreditors
                    .Include(k => k.Kontakt)
                    .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Nr == k.KtoNr),

                Sums = k.BuchZeilenKtos
                    .Where(b => b.Buch.Belegdatum.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                        && (
                            (b.GegenKto.KtoNr >= xxxxxx && b.GegenKto.KtoNr <= xxxxxx)
                            || (b.GegenKto.KtoNr >= xxxxxx && b.GegenKto.KtoNr <= xxxxxx)
                            || (b.GegenKto.KtoNr >= xxxxxx && b.GegenKto.KtoNr <= xxxxxx)
                            )
                        )
                    .GroupBy(b => b.Buch.Belegdatum.Month)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        Sum = g.Sum(b => b.Betrag * (b.SollHaben == "-" || b.SollHaben == "H" ? -1 : 1)),
                        Month = g.Key
                    }),

                Sum334 = k.BuchZeilenKtos
                    .Where(b => b.GegenKto.KtoNr >= xxxxxx && b.GegenKto.KtoNr <= xxxxxx)
                    .Sum(b => b.Betrag * (b.SollHaben == "-" || b.SollHaben == "H" ? -1 : 1))
            })
            .Where(k => k.Creditor.Kreditor && k.Sums.Any())
            .OrderBy(k => k.Creditor.Nr)
            .ToList()
```

Translations:

```
BuchzeilenKtos = Bookings
Kontens = Bank Accounts
DebitorKreditors = Customers
Buch = Booking

The bank account numbers have been removed due to privacy reasons.
```

With this I am getting the following error complaining about missing key columns:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate collection subquery in projection since it uses 'Distinct' or 'Group By' operations and doesn't project key columns of all of it's tables which are required to generate results on client side. Missing column: b.ID. Either add column(s) to the projection or rewrite query to not use 'GroupBy'/'Distinct' operation.
```

I tried numerous things including changing the GroupBy to also include the key columns:

```
                    .GroupBy(b => new
                    {
                        b.Buch.Belegdatum.Month,
                        b.Id,
                        b.GegenKto,
                        b
                    })
```

But this should produce wrong results anyway from what I understand about LINQ Grouping.

Nevertheless, Now EF is complaining about not being able to translate the query and wants me to change to clientside processing, which isn't an option due to the very high amount of bookings being processed:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<BuchZeilen>()
.Where(b => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(EntityShaperExpression:
    EntityType: Konten
    ValueBufferExpression:
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
    objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(EntityShaperExpression:
        EntityType: Konten
        ValueBufferExpression:
            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
        IsNullable: False
    , "Id"),
    objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(b, "KtoId")))
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<Buchung>(),
    outerKeySelector: b => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(b, "BuchId"),
    innerKeySelector: b0 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(b0, "Id"),
    resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<BuchZeilen, Buchung>(
        Outer = o,
        Inner = i
    ))
.LeftJoin(
    inner: DbSet<Konten>(),
    outerKeySelector: b => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(b.Outer, "GegenKtoId"),
    innerKeySelector: k0 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(k0, "Id"),
    resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<BuchZeilen, Buchung>, Konten>(
        Outer = o,
        Inner = i
    ))
.Where(b => b.Outer.Inner.Belegdatum.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && b.Inner.KtoNr >= 311000 && b.Inner.KtoNr <= 319999 || b.Inner.KtoNr >= 334000 && b.Inner.KtoNr <= 334999 || b.Inner.KtoNr >= 340000 && b.Inner.KtoNr <= 340999)
.GroupBy(
    keySelector: b => new {
        Month = b.Outer.Inner.Belegdatum.Month,
        Id = b.Outer.Outer.Id,
        GegenKto = b.Inner,
        b = b.Outer.Outer
     },
    elementSelector: b => b.Outer.Outer)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

I've read, that EF Core 5 has removed certain functionality on GroupBy/Distinct for correlated sub queries but I am not sure whether that is my exact scenario. In my opinion the query shouldn't be too specific for EF to handle.

Does anybody know how I can achieve, what I am trying to do or whether it is possible at least?